# How to map a symbolic directory link to different directories based on user id

Tags: linux, apache, filesystems, virtualization

Is there any way to a map a symbolic link directory to different directories based on the user id in Linux. For instance if a user X executes `cd /var/www/html/` then his/her directory gets changed to `/var/www/webX/`, while for the user Y it would be `/var/www/webY`. The purpose of doing this is to make the web document directories transparent for different apache users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One line answer: **No**. The linux filesystem does not support conditional symlink evaluation of the type you are envisioning.

Alternatives:

=> (Programmatically) Create symlinks in each user's home directory which point to the required location in `/var/www/`. For example, in user X's home directory:

```
ln -s /var/www/htmlX htmldir
```

In user Y's home directory:

```
ln -s /var/www/htmlY htmldir
```

So that each user can just go `cd htmldir` and get to the appropriate location.

=> Use [the per-user directory feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) to assign `~user/public_html` or more generically, `~user/<some-name-consistent-across-users>` as the HTML dir for `user`.